# Workaround for Intersection with points is not yet supported' GRASS Error

Tags: grass-gis

I am dealing with a line layer which I am unable to import properly into GRASS.
After some work solving dangles and invalid geometry issues I managed to import it, nevertheless when I try to use `v.clean.break` the software is giving this message:

```
"￼Intersection with points is not yet supported"
```

I have no idea how to deal with it.

Looking for help.

Link to file: [line layer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QnNwRaxbtWzeDB6MSoIhcBpO0vOVHx83).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the problem: in the original shapefile there seems to be a line of 0 length. THat's what is causing the "Intersection of points..." error.
All you need to do is run v.clean with both the rmline and the break tools:

```
GRASS 7.4.0 (UTM17S):~/> v.import a_linefeaturefile.shp output=a_line --o
GRASS 7.4.0 (UTM17S):~/ > v.clean a_line out=a_line_clean tool=rmline,break --o
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error when using `operator=or` and solved it by decreasing the `snap` value from 0.2 to 0.0001.

Comment: Got this error with v.overlay 'or' & 'not'.  Decreasing snap worked in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with `r.contour`. Fixed it by setting "minimum number of points for a contour" to 1 (default was 0).

Comment: this should be the default for this function